# macOS Catalina bug with openVPN : ifconfig: ioctl (SIOCDIFADDR): Can't assign requested address

Tags: macos, catalina

When I launch openVPN in the terminal, I get the following error:

```
ifconfig: ioctl (SIOCDIFADDR): Can't assign requested address
add net 10.7.0.0: gateway 10.7.0.2
add net 185.196.22.194: gateway 192.168.2.1
add net 0.0.0.0: gateway 10.7.0.1
add net 128.0.0.0: gateway 10.7.0.1
```

The bug is known (https://www.ovpn.com/en/faq/troubleshooting/mac-cant-assign-requested-address-code49):

> Can't assign requested address (code=49) is a bug in macOS and not an issue with OVPN itself.
>
> There are two ways of fixing this issue. The first one is easier as
> you simply have to restart your computer. Otherwise, you can solve the
> problem through the terminal.

but when I try the fix:

```
sudo route flush
```

after Wi-Fi is disabled, it doesn't work on my machine. I also tried rebooting and it is the same.

I have Catalina 10.15.7. Do you have any suggestions to fix this?